# PHP $-SESSION variables disappear on new page and return empty

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm having an issue with the Sessions Variables. Ever since i switched from mysqli to PDO. It worked fine with mysqli, but ever since i switched to PDO, this issue has now come forward.

I'm trying to login and i have an area, where i want to make sure that the user can only see, if the user is logged in. The login works fine, but as soon as i get referred to my index file, i don't see anything, because of the logged in function. I can see the $_SESSION Variable gets filled, but as soon as i redirect to another file, the $_SESSION Variables disappear and i get an empty Array:

```php
Array
(
)
```

process_login.php

```php
require_once('../inc/user.inc.php'); // here i have all my functions

  $user = new User(); // New Instance of my User Class

  $user -> sec_session(); // selfmade session function. I use start_session() in this function

  if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
      $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $password = filter_var ($_POST['p'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

      $login = $user -> login_user($email, $password); 

      if ($login) {
          // Login sucessful
          //print("<pre>".print_r($_SESSION,true)."</pre>"); //Here i get my $_SESSION variable printed out and it works. I see it is filled.
          header('Location: ../index.php');
          exit();
      }
```

index.php

```php
<?php
    $title = 'Index';
    $currentPage = 'Dashboard';
    include('php/head.php');
    require_once('../inc/user.inc.php');
    $user = new User();

    $user -> sec_session(); // here i call my session function again. Note: session_start() is included in this function
    print("<pre>".print_r($_SESSION,true)."</pre>"); //Now The Array is empty?!?
?>
```

user.inc.php - sec_session function

```php
protected function sec_session() {
            $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; 
            $secure = SECURE;
            $httponly = true;
            if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
            header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
            exit();
            }

            $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
            session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
                $cookieParams["path"],
                $cookieParams["domain"],
                $secure,
                $httponly);

            session_name($session_name);
            session_start();     
            session_regenerate_id(); 
        }
```

Whilst logging in, i set the Session to the following in my login function:

```php
if ($db_password == $password) {
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/",
                                                            "",
                                                            $username);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',
                          $password . $user_browser);
                return true;
              }
```

This above works all fine, but only disappears, when i land in my index.php and i know there is something worng, but i have no idea what it is.

Comment: where do you init the sessions with `session_start()` ?

Comment: This line: `if ($db_password == $password)` makes me believe that you're not hashing the passwords properly. When working with passwords, use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) (which will return a new hash everytime, even for the same string) and [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify the hash against a string.

Comment: Also, why are you storing the password hash in the session? Passwords should only have one purpose, authenticate the user. If you need some token, generate a random token that you can store together with the user in your DB instead of using the password. Passwords should be considered holy and shouldn't be used for something else than authentication. That minimizes the risk of unintentional leaks.

Comment: Are you using http or https? If you are using secure cookies PHP won't read them under http instead it starts a new session with a new cookie, switching to https solves this problem.

Comment: @treyBake i init the session_start() in the sec_session function in the process_login.php

Comment: @Mark_1 in the function sec_session i use  $httponly = false; but even then no change

Comment: It looks from your sec_session function that you are using secure cookies ($secure = SECURE;) so is your browser session using HTTPS?
If you are using HTTP with secure cookies you will start a new session on each page and won't have access to existing session variables.

Comment: @Mark_1 this may well be the error here. I'm using http on localhost. So i should switch to https right?

Comment: @Mark_1, you're absolutely right. It worked with https!! Many thanks man phew

Comment: Good news; I have converted my comments to an answer, please accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using http or https to access your local site? If you are using secure cookies PHP won't read them under http instead it starts a new session with a new cookie, switching to https solves this problem.

It looks from your sec_session function that you are using secure cookies ($secure = SECURE;) so is your browser session using HTTPS? If you are using HTTP with secure cookies you will start a new session on each page and won't have access to existing session variables.

The best solution is to access your local site with https just like you would for your live site but if you switch off the secure cookie setting for your local site that will work too.

Comment: i did. Thanks a ton!
Alhtough i keep getting the error:
Warning: Use of undefined constant SECURE - assumed 'SECURE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
This probably has to do with the https right? I type that in manually

Comment: That will be from the $secure = SECURE;
The constant SECURE is not defined, I presume that you should be setting it somewhere, you could just change your code to $secure = true; but that would lose the benefit of having a CONSTANT which applies across the whole project.

I think that $secure = SECURE; works at present because 'SECURE' (a string) evaluates to true.