# PHP Session issue "session_set_cookie_params" new session ID for different folder

Tags: php, session

Good day,

I have a nifty issue with my PHP session.
The biggest of it actually that it is working most of the time. But there are moments it is not.

I have sort of a CMS system that works as following:

(first page)
https://www.example.com/

(second page) https://www.example.com/stackoverflow-cool-site.html

(third page) https://www.example.com/houston-we-have-a-problem/what-problem-do-you-have.html

Now I have tried to set a SESSION variable at the hand of a GET param at the main page so that if the session has been set the third page can use it.
E.g.:

htts://www.example.com?set=good_weather

Now the SESSION ID set for the first page is **qavuaadh6l0b9qhmrv9unr0chc**
But I notice that the other pages give :
**2gmdggiv9k43khtsikm2eo1rvh**

And of course the Session ID can be anything and that's not so much of an issue. But it is that it's a different SESSION ID.

**Now this question has come up before**!
And the answer has been, *session_set_cookie_params*
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

However, I have done this already. And in proper order.
But probably not quite as I am supposed to.
And I am really wondering where my problem is.

```
        session_set_cookie_params(
                                    self::$limit,           /// **** LIFETIME OF THE SESSION COOKIE (in seconds)
                                    self::$path,            /// **** THE DOMAIN FOR WHERE THE COOKIE WILL WORK. (single /  for all paths on the domain.)
                                    self::$domain,          /// **** DEFINE THE DOMAIN NAME
                                    self::$secure,          /// **** ONLY BY SECURE CONNECTIONS
                                    self::$httponly         /// **** INDICATE THAT THE SESSION COOKIE IS AVAILABLE THROUGH HTTP PROTOCOLS ONLY (not by Javascript)
                                );
```

And if you fill out the variable values you get :

```
    session_set_cookie_params(
                    432000,
                    '/',
                    'example.com',
                    true,
                    true
                );
```

For what I can see and understand this should be correct. But it isn't.
I hope someone could shed light on my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

**HTTPS**
I am accessing the site over HTTPS and every call I made to the set scripts are by HTTPS only.

**Script**
I have all calls routed to the very same script. I am using a .htaccess script to make it all work.

```
DirectoryIndex core/index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: By default this should have been working without explicitly setting these parameters already … default for the path is `/`, the current host name is automatically used as the cookie domain, etc. Are you routing all those URLs to the same script, or are they different script? If the latter, did you set those same parameters in all of them?

Comment: You are using secure cookies, are you accessing the site over https?  Using secure cookies over http results in a new session each time because PHP can't read the existing cookie over an insecure connection.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294582/php-session-variables-disappear-on-new-page-and-return-empty/56361653#56361653

Answer (score 0):

You can set the session id if you want. You have to do it before session starts.