# Session is blank after saving and then changing page

Tags: php, session

I have a user system. User types in e-mail and password in a form of method=post. The post values are retrieved in another file, where it checks for these data in the database. If there is a user, the user ID is retrieved and saved as a `$user = $_SESSION["user"];`.

To make all of this more simple, we will just focus on four pages here. Two of which I have already described, the login page, the log-user-in.php page.

When the uid is saved as a session in `$user`, the user is redirected like so (`$uid` is from database):

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $uid;
header("Location: user/card.php");
exit;
```

In login.php and card.php I have echoed `session_id()` and at those two pages, they are the same AT FIRST. The problem is, when I click on subscription.php for instance, the $_SESSION["user"] is blank and the `session_id();` is a completely different id. After clicking subscription.php and clicking back to card.php that page now shows the `session_id();` from subscription.php, which means it no longer has the user ID saved in $_SESSION["user"].

If I logout and start over, everything works. I can click through all the pages and the `session_id()` is the same on all pages, and the $_SESSION["user"] HAS a user ID on all pages.

But *every time* I try this at first, the problem starts over.

I have checked every page and it has `session_start()` at the beginning of every page. I really do not know how to view some kind of error log of this problem.

**log-user-in.php**

```
<?
    session_start();
    include('includingThis.php');


    $email = addslashes($_POST[email]);
    $password = addslashes($_POST[pass]);


    $email = strtolower($email);


    // TJEK OM BRUGEREN FINDES
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, pass, uid FROM stnd_users WHERE email=?")) {


                /* bind parameters for markers */
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

                $stmt->execute(); 
                $stmt->bind_result($em, $pa, $u);

                    // Loop through each row in the result set
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                        $gottenEmail = $em;
                        $gottenPass = $pa;
                        $uid = $u;
                    }

                    $stmt->close();         
    }




        // NÅR BRUGEREN FINDES, OG KODEN ER KORREKT
        if ($uid != "") {

            $_SESSION["user"] = $uid;



                // Bruger har betalt
                if ($profile_pic == "true") {
                    header("Location: user/card.php");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    header("Location: user/profilepic.php");
                    exit;
                }


        }



?>
```

**card.php & subscription.php are identical with different content**

```
<?
    session_start();


    $user = $_SESSION["user"];


    include('../includingThis.php');


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0"/>
<title></title>
<?
    include("../logged-header.php");
?>




    <div id="container">
        <div id="headline">
            <h1>HEADLINE</h1>
        </div>

        <div align="center">
            TEXT

            <br />

            <? echo ini_get('session.cookie_domain') . "<br>"; ?>
            <? echo session_id(); ?>


    </div>

    <?
        include("../footer.php");
    ?>
    <script>
        alert(<? echo session_id(); ?>);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**logged-header.php**

```
<?php



    $style_param = 1;

    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT styles, login_button, register_button, greeting_logged_in, logout_button, leavingHeadline, leavingText, accept, cancel FROM stnd_generel WHERE id=?")) {


        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $style_param);

        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($style, $login, $register, $greet, $logout, $leavHead, $leavTxt, $ac, $canc);

        // Loop through each row in the result set
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $styles = $style;
            $login_button = $login;
            $register_button = $register;
            $greeting = $greet;
            $logout_button = $logout;
            $leaving_headline = $leavHead;
            $leaving_text = $leavTxt;
            $leaving_accept = $ac;
            $leaving_cancel = $canc;
        }

        $stmt->close();         
    }


?>
<? echo $styles; ?>
<style>
<?
if ($user == "") {
?>
#logged-in-menu {
    display: none;  
}
#login-menu {
    display: block; 
}
<?
} else {
?>
#logged-in-menu {
    display: block; 
}
#login-menu {
    display: none;  
}
<?
}
?>
.user-mobile-logged {
    display: none;  
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    <?
    if ($user != "") {
    ?>
    .user-mobile-logged {
        display: block; 
    }
    <?
    } else {
    ?>
    .user-mobile-logged {
        display: none;  
    }
    <?
    }
    ?>
    #logged-in-menu, #login-menu {
        display: none;  
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="top-nav">

        <a href="../index.php"><div id="logo"></div></a>


        <div id="menu">
        <?
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM stnd_loggedin_menu ORDER BY position ASC";     
                // Check if there are results
                if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {           
                    // Loop through each row in the result set
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        ?>
            <li id="menuDesktop">
                <a href="http://www.OOOO.com/standard/user/<? echo $row[site_link]; ?>"><? echo $row[site_name]; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?


                    }
                }


        ?>




            <li class="droping">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn"><img id="dropImg" src="http://www.OOOO.com/standard/images/nav.png" /></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <?
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM stnd_menu ORDER BY position ASC";  
                        // Check if there are results
                        if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {           
                            // Loop through each row in the result set
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {




                ?>
                <a href="../<? echo $row[site_link]; ?>"><? echo $row[site_name]; ?></a>


                <?


                        }

                    }
                ?>

                        </div>
                </div>
            </li>


        <div id="login-menu">
            <div id="no-user-login">
                <a href="login.php">
                    <div id="login-button">
                        <img src="http://www.OOOO.com/standard/images/icons/user-icon.png" /> <? echo strtoupper($login_button); ?>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="register.php">
                    <div id="register-button">
                        <img src="http://www.OOOO.com/standard/images/icons/register-icon.png" /> <? echo strtoupper($register_button); ?>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="logged-in-menu">
            <div id="user-logged">
                <a href="card.php">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="user_image">
                            <img src="http://www.OOOO.com/standard/images/<? if ($profile_pic == "true") { echo "user/" . $user . ".png"; } else { echo "icons/user_icon.png"; } ?>" />
                            <div id="logout-with-image">
                                <div style="height: 5px; width: 100%;">&nbsp;</div>
                                <a href="logout.php"><div id="logout_button"><? echo strtoupper($logout_button); ?></div></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li id="user_info">
                            <? echo $greeting; ?><br />
                            <font id="user_name"><? echo $firstname; ?></font>
                            <br /><br />
                            <a href="logout.php"><div id="logout_button"><? echo strtoupper($logout_button); ?></div></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This line is wrong `addslashes($_POST[pass]);` it should be `$_POST['pass']`

Comment: @Dharman may I ask why?

Comment: You do not have a constant defined `pass` or `email`, and you should never transform user passwords in any way. `addslashes` seems to serve no purpose in your code. On top of that you do not use `$password` anywhere in your code, but I assume you have not shown us everything.

Comment: Are you using http or https on your site? If you are using secure cookies then this answer may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294582/php-session-variables-disappear-on-new-page-and-return-empty/56361653#56361653